# Multiple parquet files in Power BI from Azure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We want to use Databricks to generate flat files in our Azure data lake to be used as the data source for a Power BI dashboard. We've chosen to generate them as Parquet files, and Databricks generates multiple files. The problem is that we can't find a way to get Power BI to use this as a source:

- If we use the Parquet connector you have to specify a specific file. Changing the source to a folder location is not allowed.
- Using a folder source doesn't work because it wants an absolute path, not a URL.
- Using an Azure Data Lake connector works *only if* you delete the `_committed_` and `_started_` prefixed files also generated by Databricks. This isn't going to work as we need the data files to be regenerated every night for the dashboard to update.

How can we make this work? Thank you!

Comment: Use Azure Synapse Serverless, add the files as an external table, and load via normal SQL connection, or generate them into csv files and use load from folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959153/multiple-parquet-files-in-power-bi-from-azure/70985504#comment125457267_70959153) provided the answer: we're now using Synapse Serverless with a view over the data lake files. This keeps our pipeline working as-is and gives the Power BI developers and easy way (once you get the permissions sorted...) to connect and retrieve the data. Thank you!

Comment: If we want to show a Power BI report linking to Azure Synapse Serverless, do we need to turn on Synapse for entire business hours? Therefore the charge will be 5 days x 8 hours?

Comment: Depends on how your Power BI report is built. If it's Direct Query mode, then yes, as the report will be trying to read the data every time. If you've built it in Import mode then Synapse would only need to be on when the dataset refreshes.

Comment: I should also add that we lost confidence in this when we found the views were not always returning all the rows available and MS couldn't explain to us why. We now have Power BI read directly from databricks.

Comment: Our BI report is reading parquet files directly from dfs.core.windows.net link. Usually it works but the dataset will fail to refresh from time to time. We need to fix by re-create the parquet files.